# "Should you visit our Web site" What nuance does it have?

Tags: sentence-construction, conditionals

> 'You can find an updated event schedule should you visit our Web site this Friday.'

So, the answer is 'c'. That's good.
But I have a question. Is this expression of

> 'Should you visit our Web site this Friday'

natural?

If so, what is difference between (a) and (b) below (i.e., between 'Should you' and 'If you')?

(a). Should you visit our Web site this Friday, you can find an updated event schedule. 
(b). If you visit our Web site this Firday, you can find an updated event schedule.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of **should** in this context is this one:

> **[should](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/should)** modal verb (POSSIBILITY)
>   *formal*
>   used when referring to a possible event in the future

Note the word *formal* in this definition. I would be unlikely to use it in speech, and would only use it in writing in a very formal context, for example a letter to an important and very officious person.

Comment: +1 for noting the formality, and I'd say it's a bit antiquated too. More natural is "You can find ... on our website this Friday."

Comment: Agreeing with the answer and comment, I would also add that the test sentence is badly written. It uses the outdated form “Web site” instead of the widely accepted modern form “website” (https://grammarist.com/spelling/web-site-website/). By its very nature a sentence like this, publicising a schedule on a website, must invariably use an informal tone or at least not an excessively formal one as this use of the modal verb suggests. For these reasons I would claim the test question is a ridiculous one.